# Is it possible to purchase characters before I complete story mode?

Tags: lego-marvel-avengers

I have unlocked a character or three whose abilities I want to utilise in levels in Free Play mode.  However, I can't work out how to buy them.

In previous games, it was possible to go to some sort of terminal in the hub to switch character even before you'd completed the story mode to unlock free play for the hubs - and you could buy characters there.  For example, Lego Marvel Super Heroes (at SHIELD terminals) and Lego Batman 3 (at character switch terminals) both had this ability.

Is this possible in Lego Avengers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the same Vehicle Call In Points are available in the hubs - primarily Manhattan, because it's the largest (not sure about the other hubs, I haven't spent much time there yet).  These allow you to both purchase and switch characters, even prior to story completion.  Here's what they look like; this is an air one, the land ones are similar but blue instead of red:
[image]

Here's a map of Manhattan, originating in the Prima Guide, which includes the location of the Vehicle Call In Points, both land (blue) and air (red):
[image]